# center <IMG/> inside a <DIV> with CSS

Tags: html, css, centering

I want to center image inside a div. The div has fixed width 300px. The image width is known only at runtime. It usually is bigger then 300px, so image should be centered and cut right and left. margin 0 auto does not work in this case.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

div{width:300px;border:1px solid red; overflow:hidden}

img{
/* NOTE!!!!
margin:auto; doesn't work when image width is bigger than div width
image width is known only at runtime!!!
*/
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <img src="" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for any css ideas

---

**UPD**  This interesting task is followed **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4974991/block-inside-a-block-drawing-border-around-the-visible-area-untrivial-task)**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can make it work if you wrap another element around the image:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
.outer {
    width: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    overflow: hidden;
    *position: relative;
}
.inner {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
}
img {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

The `position: relative` on the `.outer` is marked with `*` so it only applies to IE6/7. You could move it to a conditional IE stylesheet if that's what you prefer, or remove the `*` altogether. It's needed to avoid the now relatively positioned children from overflowing.

Comment: Your method works! Do you have any crazy idea of making the border around the (cropped or not) image? Not outer border, not image border, but border around the visible part of the image? My IQ is too low to do this...

Answer (score 13):

Giving the `div` `text-align: center` should work. (You may have to add `align='center'` as a property for it to work in IE6, though.) **Note**: As pointed out by @streetpc, this method will not work properly if the image is wider than the container.

Alternatively, you could also have the image as a background image:

```
background-image: url(url);
background-position: center top;
```

Comment: If your div has `text-align: center`, check the img has `display: inline` (or `inline-block`), but the image will be cropped to the right only.

Comment: @streetpc you're right, it won't center with the first method if the image is wider than the container. A background image would indeed be the best way to go then (or alternatively, an inlying div with a huge fixed width- but that is hacky)

Comment: Consider that background images may not be printed, couldn't be replaced at runtime in a generic way, it's possible that the crawlers don't get it (google images, for example), and you can use `max-width` to limit the image size.

Comment: @Gonzalo all good points except for the last one IMO - `max-width` will resize the image which I don't think is the OP's intent.

Answer (score 2):

To center an image at the center of an html page:

```
<p style="text-align:center; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; padding:0px;">
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image"/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS transform to position the element:

```
div { position: relative; } 
img { position: absolute; left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%); }
```