# css: image cropped by block. drawing border around the visible area. Untrivial question

Tags: css, border, center

1. suppose we have a visible area 300 x 200 pixels
2. suppose we have an image of any size. It can be bigger or smaller than the visible area.

Question:

1.center the image vertically and horizontally inside the visible area. Crop overflowing parts of the image
  1a. vertical centering is unimportant and can be omitted

2.draw the border around the visible part of the image. Note that the border can match either the outer div border or image border

2a.**clarification**: I want to find the way of (for example) creating the third div whose borders would repeat the borders of the visual part of the image

Cropped or not, in browser has to be seen the border around the visible part of the image

[mercator](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23263/mercator) has already done some of the job [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958385/center-img-inside-a-div-with-css) as described below:

> You can make it work if you wrap
>   another element around the image:
>
> ```
> <div class="outer">
>   <div class="inner"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
> </div>
> ```
>
> And the following CSS:
>
> ```
> .outer {
>   width: 300px;
>     height: 200px;
>   border: 1px solid red;
>   overflow: hidden;
>   *position: relative;
> }
> .inner {
>   float: left;
>   position: relative;
>   left: 50%;
> }
> img {
>   display: block;
>   position: relative;
>   left: -50%;
> }
> ```
>
> The `position: relative` on the
>   `'outer` is marked with `*` so it will
>   only work in IE6/7. You could move it
>   to a conditional IE stylesheet if
>   that's what you prefer, or remove the
>   `*` altogether. It's needed to avoid
>   the now relatively positioned children
>   from overflowing.

Comment: to develop html/css for drawing the border around the visible part of the image. I think it's a difficult trick. It can become a useful pattern if developed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not to sure what you mean by your *2d* clarification, but I think you can achieve this with the follow markup:

```
<div class="outer"></div>
```

and css:

```
.outer {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background: #fff url(/path/to/image.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

This will create a `div` of 300x200px with a 1px red border. It will then position an image in the div centered vertically and horizontally, or default to white the image cannot be found.

Comment: You are right. This can be pretty solved by backgrounds.This is what I do as a fallback when JS disabled. However the backgrounds are not indexed by Google (am I right?). So I use JS to position image in the center

Answer (score 0):

The border, you'll need to draw in another fashion. Simple borders can be added using css. More complex borders and shadows are limited in css and only implemented in some browsers, but you can use javascript to help you add a more complex shadow. There are many snippets and [jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/shadow) that can help you.

You can center the image in the visible area by giving it `margin-left` = `margin-right` = `auto`.

Comment: see clarification. the image will not center using margin:auto if it is wider then 300px

Comment: Difficult. You'll probably need some javascript. Maybe the best solution is to create a fixed size 'visible area' div and center the image as a background. Then, create and center a div inside it to draw the border and size that div using javascript to the right size of the image, with a maximum size.