# How to center an img inside a div

Tags: html, css, margin

I'm trying something that should be pretty easy but i can't figure out how to make it.

I have html source like this:

```
<div class="product">
  <img src="product123.png" />
</div>`
```

And some css:

```
.product {
    width: 460px;
    height: 460px;
}

.product img {
      margin: auto;
      display: block;
}
```

My image is well horizontally-aligned but not vertically. I tried with some `position: relative; / bottom: 0;` feature but it didn't change anything...

Any idea guys ?

Thank you for your help !

PS: I found this solution [center <IMG/> inside a <DIV> with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958385/center-img-inside-a-div-with-css) but I'd rather prefer keeping my HTML like this and it seems like unbelievable to not be able to do it "my" way.

Comment: [Understanding vertical-align, or "How (Not) To Vertically Center Content"](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/tG9UK/

```
.product {
    width: 460px;
    height: 460px;

    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to center both vertically and horizontally, you should be able to apply display: table-cell to the div and use vertical-align

```
.product {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    width: 460px;
    height: 460px;
}
.product img {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.product {
    width: 460px;
    height: 460px;
    line-height:460px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EHTeL/1/

Answer (score 0):

If the image dimensions are static then something like this would work for you

```
.product img {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   margin-top: -150px; /* Half the height */
   margin-left: -150px; /* Half the width */
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have precised that my image dimensions are not static.