# Centering an image in a div by setting CSS values dynamically with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to center an image in a div according to the width of the image after I scale it to have a height of 250px.

For example, if I had an image with dimensions 625x450 and, in my CSS file, set the height of the image to be 250px, then the width would automatically scale to 347.22px. I want to be able to detect that scaled width and then set a margin-left of (width - height)/2 to center the image.

The CSS for this example in hard-coded form would look like this (the entire fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/davidsawyer/99PMd/5/)):

```
.gallery {
    width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.gallery img {
    height: 250px;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: -48px;
}
```

But I want to be able to do this on the fly with images of other dimensions. I have attempted to do this by cutting out the margin-left line of the hard-coded CSS and adding some jQuery (the entire fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/davidsawyer/99PMd/4/)):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    oldWidth = $('.gallery img').width();
    newMarg = (oldWidth - 250)/2);       
    $('.gallery img').css("margin-left", newMarg);
}
```

I have not had any success with that approach, though. It has to be something with the jQuery that I'm messing up. I'm very new to everything I'm attempting to do here, and I feel like I might be missing something simple.

Comment: I think this might be your solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958385/center-img-inside-a-div-with-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958385/center-img-inside-a-div-with-css)

I changed your jsFiddle to adapt to the concept in that post:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99PMd/14/)

```
<div class="outer">
   <div class="inner">
       <img src="" />
   </div>
</div>
```

and

```
.outer {
  width: 250px; overflow: hidden;
}
.inner {
  float: left; position: relative; left: 50%;
}
.inner img {
  height: 250px; display: block; position: relative; left: -50%;
}
```

Plus side of this solution is that it isn't javascript dependant

Comment: Yes! This works perfectly. Is it better practice to less CSS handle all this as opposed to JS?

Comment: I'm no expert, but it should be better at least from the point of view that this no longer requires javascript to be activated in the client's browser. If that were the case, they would see the uncentered version of the image.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the image to display:block, you can use margin: 0 auto;text-align:center;

Comment: I tried that [here](http://jsfiddle.net/davidsawyer/99PMd/8/). It didn't seem to work. Am I missing something?

Comment: That image is larger than the div containing it, so centering is impossible using the `margin: auto` technique.

Comment: Is something like my jQuery technique a way to do it?

Comment: Yes, you're trying to "overflow" the centering, so you'll need to use some JavaScript in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from some misplaced parentheses, you had your subtraction backwards:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    oldWidth = $('.gallery img').width();
    newMarg = (250 - oldWidth) / 2;
    $('.gallery img').css("margin-left", newMarg);
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/99PMd/10/

Please note, however, that if there's more than one `.gallery` or `img` inside of it, the variable `oldWidth` will equal only the first such image that's found in the DOM. If you have several such images or several galleries, you'll need to refactor your code with a loop:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.gallery img').each(function() {
        oldWidth = $(this).width();
        newMarg = (250 - oldWidth) / 2;
        $(this).css("margin-left", newMarg);
    });
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/99PMd/11/

Now personally, I find overflowing an image like that unattractive, so I'd just resize the image to fit its container. This CAN be done with pure CSS:

```
.gallery img {
    height: auto;
    max-width:100%;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/99PMd/12/

Answer (score 0):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99PMd/13/)

```
$(window).load(function(){

   var galW = 250;
   var imgW = $('.gallery img').width();

   if(imgW>galW){
       $('.gallery img').css({marginLeft: (galW-imgW)/2 })   ;
   }

});
```