# Vertical centering of a SVG img within a Div using CSS

Tags: html, css

Inside a div I have an img tag that refers to a SVG file. I would like to center this image vertically and horizontally in the div. The target is IE 9/10 and FF. 
I've tried various suggestions from the various CSS sites but nothing seems to give me the expected vertical spacing/centering. The SVG file will have its size changed via jscript so the centering has to be "dynamic".

Here is my latest CSS:

```
.bigbox {
border: 1px solid #808080;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
display: table;
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
}
img {
width: 95%;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;
display: table-cell;
}
```

The HTML:

```
 <div class="bigbox">
        <img src="LOGOo2.svg"/>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4958522/1524085

Comment: If your `.bigbox` has fixed height, add `line-height:100px` to `.bigbox`.