# I want set all <div class="rectangle"> tag borders in a center

Tags: html, css

```
 _______________________________________________
|                                               |
|    Image                                      |
|                                               |
|_______________________________________________|
```

I want set a above rectangle  is in center in a page  i created that using div tag as code is

```
.rectangle
{
     width: 73.3%;
     margin:0 50 0 0;         
     border-top:1px solid #46464f;
     border-bottom:1px solid #282832;
     border-left:1px solid #282832;
     border-right:1px solid #282832;
     border-bottom-width:medium;
     border-left-width:medium;
     border-right-width:medium;
     border-top-width:medium;
}
```

I set `<div class="rectangle" align="center">` this code not working

Comment: Try to get something from [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237636/how-to-vertically-center-image-inside-div). Might be same case.

Comment: [**Here's**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4958385/center-img-inside-a-div-with-css) another topic related.

Comment: Just to be clear for I'm already confuse on what you really want. Do you want to set your `<DIV>` tags be in the center of the page? Not the image or content inside the `<DIV>`?

Comment: To make things a little more readable you could try compacting your CSS by combining the borders: `.rectangle {width: 73.3%; margin 0 50px 0 0; border: medium solid #282832; border-top-color: #46464f;}`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

HTML:

```
<div align="center">
     <img src="http://fin6.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/fb81531cc9cf1512dce7f0e5f36e40fe.jpg" alt="nature"/>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
     width: 300px;
     background:red;
     margin:0 auto;
}

img{
     width:150px;
     margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/65S4f/)**

**UPDATE**

As per your updated question, use `margin:0 auto;` to center div.

```
.rectangle
{
     width: 73.3%;
     margin:0 auto;
     border-top:1px solid #46464f;
     border-bottom:1px solid #282832;
     border-left:1px solid #282832;
     border-right:1px solid #282832;
     border-bottom-width:medium;
     border-left-width:medium;
     border-right-width:medium;
     border-top-width:medium;
}
```

Updated **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/65S4f/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS code:

```
.rectangle
{
    width: 73.3%; margin:0 50 0 0; 
    border-top:1px solid #46464f; 
    border-bottom:1px solid #282832; 
    border-left:1px solid #282832; 
    border-right:1px solid #282832; 
    border-bottom-width:medium; 
    border-left-width:medium; 
    border-right-width:medium; 
    border-top-width:medium;   
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="setCenter">Content inside a div tag</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:auto;
}

.setCenter {
    margin:auto;
    width:90%;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid #000;
    color:Green;
}
```

Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gy95N/)**