# How to center image vertically inside div element?

Tags: css, image, center

I have a question, how can I center the image inside the div? to have text on the left and image on the right. The height of this div is not set in the CSS, because I want it to increase automatically if I add more text, and I want the image be always centered vertically. Is this possible?

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="text">
      <h2>Hello</h2>                                                                            
         <p>BlaBLA BLA BLA</p>  
   </div>
   <div class="pic">
      <img src="img/images/img-producent_53_53.jpg"  />                          
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I update my post to example of code i have

Comment: Try use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4958522/2652540) approach for centered img.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS table cell + vertical align feature.

```
.text, .pic {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

The "clear" div won't be necessary if you do it this way.

```css
.text, .pic {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="text">
      <h2>Hello</h2>                                                                            
         <p>BlaBLA BLA BLA</p>  
   </div>
   <div class="pic">
      <img src="img/images/img-producent_53_53.jpg"  />                          
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed you could but one probably shouldn't since it's not data.

Comment: This dont work for me:(

Comment: @Gad can you tell me which part didn't work?

Comment: I copy you code .. and try fit to my And when im adding text picturce dosent center vertically it stay where it is.

Comment: @Gad it seems to be working fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/hs61v9hm/

Comment: @Shikkediel . Do not mistake and be wise :`display` doesn't change the tag/html structure .  CSS has nothing to do with HTML content, **it only styles it** (do you think that `display:none;` remove the tags from html ? )

Comment: Yea..that what i want to achive ... Maybe beacuse i have this css propetis for this div 
.pic {
 padding-right:25px;
 float:right;
}
.txt {
 width:300px;
 float:left;

that dosent work

Comment: @Gad , you said it :), remove the float and let the display be efficient

Comment: Yeap .. float block it ... Now it work fine . Thank you very much ... Have Good Day

Comment: @Gad great, don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Thanks for the help of troubleshooting :) @GCyrillus

Comment: I am wise and not a fan of patronisation, @GCyrillus. Displaying elements as if they were data is the last thing I'd resort to. I know it's popular but it's still a hack and there are much slicker approaches out there.

Comment: @Shikkediel for me, as long as the markup structure makes sense, what you do with CSS doesn't really matter. whatever the easiest way is should be considered as a good solution. fyi, If you look closer into Bootstrap it uses lots of `table-cell` stuff for non data structure. And you feel free to post a better answer if you have as always.

Comment: @Shikkediel thereis no hack in using value such as table/table-cell/list-item/inline-block/flex or whatever. there is no semantics in CSS.

Comment: It may not be wrong but it feels gross, lol. Doesn't make it right just because Bootstrap does it...

Comment: @Shikkediel i'm not saying Bootstrap does it right or wrong, in fact I rarely use it on my projects. Just saying it as an example, to tell it's being used widely.

Comment: I'm not hating, just liking in another direction... this would serve best when deep browser support is required.